# Cannot convert a string array position(2.6) in double new double array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, double, converters

I have a string array which have different types of symbols. I divided it into separate elements, and now one of them is my `2.6`. I just want him to convert, but gives me an error, tried different methods and written me:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

```
string s = Console.ReadLine(); // Input "Apr\2.6\7\300";
string[] array = s.Split('\\'); // array is with separeted: Apr  2.6  7  300

double[] num = new double[3];  
num[0] = double.Parse(intArray[1]); // Help me for this Convert ! :)
```

Comment: `intArray` is not declared on your example. is it `array`?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your current culture has a different decimal separator.

You can specify the invariant culture for the parsing, which has a period as decimal separator:

```
num[0] = double.Parse(array[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```